# Standard-in parse errors with bc command

Tags: bash, macos, awk, scripting, bc

I'm trying to perform some floating point arithmetic in bash and I get these errors in terminal:

```
$
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

The code that is throwing these errors is:

```sh
qlen=$(awk '{print $2 ; exit}' $filepath/result)
slen=$(awk '{print $3 ; exit}' $filepath/result)

len=$(awk  'BEGIN{max = 0} {if (($4) > max)  max = ($4)} END {print max}' $filepath/result)
qcov=$(echo $len / $qlen | bc -l) #parse error 2
scov=$(echo $len / $slen | bc -l) #parse error 2

if (( $(echo "$qcov >= .7" | bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$scov >= .7" | bc -l) )) #parse error 1???
then 
    score=$(awk '{ total += $1; count++ } END { if (count > 0) {printf "%f", total/count} }'  $filepath/result) #parse error 1???
else
    score=0
fi
```

I find the max number in column `$4` and divide it by the numbers in column `$2` and `$3`.  I want the floating point result, not integer arithmetic.  I save this floating point number into `qcov` and `scov` and use a conditional operator within the if-statement.  I think I've narrowed down the exact lines where these parse errors are occurring which are commented above.  They all stem from the `bc` command.

The input file `$filepath/result` looks like this:

```
34.234 234 756 34 3 34
76.542 234 756 7 64 76
63.357 234 756 97 5 35
```

You can see this file as a space delimited table.  Column `$2` and `$3` are always the same number, so, the awk statement assigning `qlen` and `slen` should behave as expected with the `exit` statement.

My best guess is that there is some problem when the if-statement evaluates to true, but I don't quite understand what is going wrong beyond that.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone who helped, I figured out why I got these errors.  The file `result` is being created every time I call this set of code.  There were cases where the program creating it would not print anything, resulting in EOF (?) at the beginning and causing the parse errors I got.  I]m fairly certain that is why I got parse errors.

Comment: I don't know what's causing the error, but you can try putting `set -x` before this code, so the shell will print things as it executes them, and see if that shows what the problem is.

Comment: Reduce your code to a **minimal** example that produces the problem you're asking about. Chances are by doing that you'll figure out the issue for yourself.

Comment: I don't get any parse errors with the code and data you posted even when I change test thresholds to force different code paths to be followed. Use `set -x` as Gordon suggests.

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you do so many shell operations when you have the full power of `awk`.

find the max of column 4 and divide by columns 2 and 3.

```
$  awk 'NR==FNR{if(max<$4) max=$4; next} {print max/$2, max/$3}' file{,}

0.41453 0.128307
0.41453 0.128307
0.41453 0.128307
```

I didn't understand what you do next, but you should be able to add to this script easily as well.

Comment: I see, That single awk statement will be useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Justin: Your file `result` has several lines. Hence, `qlen` and `slen` is a string with several numbers embedded. You can see this problem immediately, when you run your script with `-x`.

Comment: yes I agree, This is why I have the extra exit statement within those awk statements since the columns for `qlen` and `slen` are always the same.  I should have clarified this and in my question.  I thought using the exit would be a clever way to to solve this issue.

Comment: If you are looking just for the values of the first line, a `head -n 1  result|awk ...` would be more appropriate. Still, it would be helpful if you would also show the output of an execution with `set -x`.